# What does a dollar sign followed by a question mark mean in Perl?

Tags: perl

In the following in Perl script:

```
$a=apple
$b=orange

if ($?==0) {
  # do something
}
```

What does `$?` mean here?

Comment: I wish it were easier to Google for this sort of thing directly without having to know what you're looking for...

Comment: bash also has a `$?` variable with a similar function

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I don't know whether http://symbolhound.com was already there 6 years ago, but now it is. Try http://symbolhound.com/?q=perl+%24%3F. They say _"SymbolHound is a search engine that doesn't ignore special characters. This means you can easily search for symbols like &, %, and π."_

Answer (score 14):

This is the status returned by the last system operation, pipe, or backtick operation.  See reference [perlvar](http://p3rl.org/var#%24CHILD_ERROR).

Comment: Good: that reference actually explains how to unpack the wait status 16-bit quantity. However, on a traditional Uɴɪx system the terminating signal numbers is `($? & 127)`, whereas the coredump flag is `($? & 128)`. The child exit status is `($? >> 8)`. I don’t know what happens with systems that have more bits for signals than those.

Answer (score 10):

`$?`, along with all the other "magic" variables, is documented in the `perlvar` section of the Perl manpages. If you don't actually have a Unix-like setup with the `man` command, you should also be able to Google for `man perlvar`.

Comment: I think this is not a valid answer. It's OK to reference the documentation, but the idea of SO is to have specific questions with specific answers.

Answer (score 5):

Others have answered the question about the meaning of `$?`.

I thought I would also mention that it is also possible to get help on Perl's special variables at the command prompt:

```
perldoc -v $?
```

Depending on your shell, you may need to escape the `$`.

[perldoc -h](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldoc.html)

Answer (score 4):

$? or $CHILD_ERROR (if use English) contains the status of the last backtic (or several means of running a child process from Perl.) See [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24CHILD_ERROR) for a full explanation.

Comment: as of matter of fact, I am getting 256 before shifting, so after shifting I am getting 1. Why 1? is there a database of error code describing the error code

Comment: anyhow, i found out the batch script is returning some error because i use findstr, so at the end of batch script triggered by this perl script, i inserted a echo command to trick it to believe everything is ok...