# What is the meaning of the built-in variable $? in Perl

Tags: perl, system

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [perl “dollar sign and question mark” question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287635/perl-dollar-sign-and-question-mark-question)

I am trying to understand the Perl  script written by someone. I don't understand the use of `$?` in the script. Can anyone explain me the purpose of below line?

```
 system( "perform_task.sh", "-param1");
    if( ( $? >> 8 ) != 0 ) {
       print( "perform_task.sh failed " );
    }
```

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To find the meaning of any variable, you can either type

```
$ perldoc -v '$?'
```

on the command line with relatively recent versions of Perl or scan `perldoc perlvar` installed on your computer. Usually, it is best to read the documentation for the specific version of `perl` you have, but in a pinch, bearing in mind any possible gotchas due to version differences, the online version will do as well: [perldoc -v '$?'](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24?):

> The status returned by the last pipe close, backtick (``` `` ```) command, successful call to `wait()` or `waitpid()`, or from the `system()` operator. This is just the 16-bit status word returned by the traditional Unix `wait()` system call (or else is made up to look like it). Thus, the exit value of the subprocess is really `($? >> 8)`, and `$? &amp; 127` gives which signal, if any, the process died from, and `$? & 128` reports whether there was a core dump.

Further information can be gleaned from the documentation for [perldoc -f system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html):

> If you'd like to manually inspect "system"'s failure, you can check all possible failure modes by inspecting `$?` like this:

```
   if ($? == -1) {
       print "failed to execute: $!\n";
   }
   elsif ($? & 127) {
       printf "child died with signal %d, %s coredump\n",
           ($? & 127),  ($? & 128) ? 'with' : 'without';
   }
   else {
       printf "child exited with value %d\n", $? >> 8;
   }
```

While there is nothing wrong with asking even elementary questions on Stackoverflow, if you actually want to become a capable programmer, you'll need to get into the habit of reading the documentation yourself, and develop the capacity to understand it yourself.

Otherwise, you'll waste valuable time you could be using to solve problems instead on waiting for others to read the documentation for you.

It really doesn't affect the rest of us if you choose never to expend any effort in trying to understand documentation, but it will hurt you in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

The `use English;` name for the `$?` is `$CHILD_ERROR`. It is child's exit status including possible signal number that caused it exit. See `perldoc perlvar`.

Answer (score -1):

$? is the error code of the child process (perform_task.sh).

In the case of your script the return code is shifted eight bits to the right and the result compared with 0. 
This means the run is considered a failure only if the returned code is > than 255.

Comment: Thats wonderful!..now i understand what it actually mean in the code..thanks for the elaborative answer..

Comment: The reason for the bit shift is that `$?` contains the full 16 bit status returned by the POSIX `wait()` function which includes both the process's return code and the signal number, if any, that killed it. The test fails if the return code is non-zero.